# How to contact pre-law students and teachers for a legal research project?

Tags: florida, legal-research, ohio

A True Crime Youtube creator features high-school pre-law students to read the female part in a deposition he publishes in video form.

The young women I have seen are unpracticed and intimidated by the camera. Still IMO their fresh appearance and innocent demeanor make them *naturals*.

The creator is a succesful personal injury attorney; maybe the student talent he publishes is the fruit of his professional reputation or perhaps it is due to personal relationships.

Then, I got to thinking of these fresh pre-law students reading-out passages in the complete GMail Record of the cooperative for dramatic effect. Then, again, we could do that ourselves.

Then I thought: what if these young students undertake a research project, reviewing the evidence and reading the legal statutes that might be relevant?

The research does not imply responsibility of any kind. If the students discover
that the Mexican craftwomen are derelicts they can publish that as their result.

It's a model legal research project involving the cataloguing of evidence and the report as to the statues and federal laws and of different states.

This could be a useful extra-credit project to build out the pattern of a case.
Its for a real lawyer to put the fact patterns and the laws into a lawsuit suit.

It would be delightful to work with USA students in a healthy collaborative way.

How could one locate pre-law programs at high-school, preparatory and university-level?

How might one  compose a correct and effective letter proposing the legal research project.

Comment: Typically, at least in the US, "pre-law" has a specific meaning of an undergraduate student, not typically in (public) high school. I don't know of any public high school that offers "pre-law" programs. There are [youth programs for those interested in law](https://www.nslcleaders.org/youth-leadership-programs/law-advocacy/) but they are typically run by specialized groups or colleges.

Comment: To add to @RonBeyer, in there may be students who are in undergraduate studies who intend to attend law scool, but there is not really a definition of pre-law programs.  US law schools only require an undergraduate degree, without any other requirements.

Comment: Maybe it is a extracurricular club of students who intend to study law?

Comment: 'youth programs for those interested in law' Thank you for this valuable resource

Comment: Moot court clubs, prelaw clubs, prelaw advisors, and criminal justice major faculty, would be natural starting points. Debate club team members would also often have a pre-law orientation.

Comment: How to contact moot court clubs, prelaw clubs, prelaw advisors? Any ideas.

Comment: Since 1989, the National Student Leadership Conference has invited a select group of outstanding middle school and high school students to participate in its fast-paced interactive summer sessions. Sponsored by the National Student Leadership Foundation, a 501(c)3 nonprofit, nonpartisan, education organization, the NSLC provides students with the opportunity to experience life on a college campus, develop essential leadership skills, and explore a future career through exciting simulations, exclusive site visits and interactive meetings. I wrote NSLC this morning.